# FreeType - Wrong advance.x value after FT_Get_Glyph is used

Tags: c++, freetype, freetype2

After following some examples how to render, [like this one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_01), i figured that i will probably need some form of caching. While my caching is rendering fine i struggle to get the correct advance-value of the glyph.

Following code will be enough to demonstrate that function `FT_Get_Glyph` will make the value different. (`find / -name FreeSans.ttf` or [link](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/freefont/) if you need to copy/download the font)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <freetype2/ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include FT_GLYPH_H

int main() {
    std::map<GLchar, FT_BitmapGlyph> glyphs;
    FT_Library ftLibrary;
    FT_Face ftFace;

    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ftLibrary)) {
        printf("Could not initialize FreeType library\n");
        return GL_TRUE;
    }
    if (FT_New_Face(ftLibrary, "FreeSans.ttf", 0, &ftFace)) {
        printf("Could not load selected font\n");
        return GL_TRUE;
    }
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(ftFace, 0, 48);
    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++) {
        if (FT_Load_Char(ftFace, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
            printf("Could not load character, continuing\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Advance: %li\n", ftFace->glyph->advance.x >> 6);
        if (FT_Get_Glyph(ftFace->glyph, (FT_Glyph *)&glyphs[c])) {
            printf("Could not copy the glyph\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Advance after get: %li\n", glyphs[c]->root.advance.x >> 6);
        printf("Advance after with cast: %li\n", ((FT_Glyph)glyphs[c])->advance.x >> 6);
        if (glyphs[c]->root.format == FT_GLYPH_FORMAT_BITMAP) {
            printf("Format is bitmap!\n");
        }
    }

    FT_Done_Face(ftFace);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ftLibrary);
}
```

Output

```
Advance: 16
Advance after get: 16384
Advance after with cast: 16384
Format is bitmap!
Advance: 28
Advance after get: 28672
Advance after with cast: 28672
Format is bitmap!
Advance: 34
Advance after get: 34816
Advance after with cast: 34816
Format is bitmap!
```

Freetype themself write this in their reference manual, [link](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-glyph_management.html#FT_BitmapGlyphRec):

> You can typecast an FT_Glyph to FT_BitmapGlyph if you have
>   ‘glyph->format == FT_GLYPH_FORMAT_BITMAP’. This lets you access the
>   bitmap's contents easily.

and this about the root-field:

> The root FT_Glyph fields.

Which, atleast for me, says that i should be able to access original fields from `FT_Glyph` through the `->root`.

Obviously this doesnt work, so my questions are, have i misunderstood something?

So, while i researched information to this question i stumbled over this information, [link](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-glyph_management.html#FT_Get_Glyph)

> Because ‘*aglyph->advance.x’ and '*aglyph->advance.y' are 16.16
>   fixed-point numbers, ‘slot->advance.x’ and ‘slot->advance.y’ (which
>   are in 26.6 fixed-point format) must be in the range ]-32768;32768[.

Since `glyphs[c]->root.advance.x >> 16 == ftFace->glyph->advance.x >> 6` i can see some connection between 16:16 and 26:6 although these numbers doesnt say me anything, yet.

Can someone explain how this adds up? Why change ratio(or whatever these numbers are) and do i understand it correct that the right way of accessing advance-values after `FT_Get_Glyph` is `glyphs[c]->root.advance.x >> 16`?

(i realize that i probably answered my own question for the most part, but since i didnt find any information/questions about this i figured i will post it anyway, as a reference to others)

Comment: `x.y` means `x` bits for integer part and `y` bits for fractional part. Right-shifting by `y` truncates the value. Here `x+y == 32` to make the numbers fit nicely into 32-bit integers.

Comment: Why do you tag this question as "OpenGL" ? Freetype has nothing to do with OpenGL.